# Can't find VSIX Project Type in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I have installed the VS 2010 SDK but I still don't have the VSIX project type.  This system has never had any beta bits on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK so I'm a dummy... you have to target .NET 4 to see that project type.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but first download and install the SDK :

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en