# VSIX project template does not exist

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have VS2010 with SP1 installed on it. Still I am not getting VSIX project template in "New Project" dialogue box.

I have referred following question too but no luck

[Can't find VSIX Project Type in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766566/cant-find-vsix-project-type-in-vs-2010)

Any clues?
[image]

Comment: Have you turned on logging with `devenv.exe /log` ?  Apparently there is a bug that prevents templates from being loaded that are installed in a path longer than 260 characters: [https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534797](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534797)

Comment: Make sure you select .NET 4 as the target framework. For VS2012, it only shows when .NET 4.5 is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've installed the Visual Studio SP1 SDK - available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21835).

That has the proper templates you're looking for

EDIT: 
Check `<drive>:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\VSSDK\` -- that's where (I think) the extensions should have been installed to. You should see a number of sub directories. See if this matches with your install:

- ProjectTemplates

  - CSharp

    - **VSIXProject.zip**

If that file's not present, it would suggest that something went wrong with your install of the SDK.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your VS install's Help -> About dialog?

Comment: What edition of VS does it show? IIRC, VSIX project types aren't supported in Express (in the very least)

Answer (score 1):

Installed extensions from 
    [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2680)

with some hookups [resolved from this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/ac4fab28-ab07-4b3c-b46c-8b6b293068c8/)